# How to do I use PHP long integers?

Tags: php

In PHP, how do I use a long integer value without the use of any third party library?

I would like to calculate 2 to the 65th power.

Comment: the information is preserved, number is just worked with as float, if you want to output whole string try this `echo sprintf('%0.0f',2**65);`
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5092f272d7f02873b24828411cbd6aa0faf3ace

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo sprintf('%0.0f',pow(2,65));
```

Output will be:

```
36893488147419103232
```

Note: you can also use `Printf`

```
echo printf('%0.0f',pow(2,65));
```